# Formula for area of clusters in kmeans

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-means

With the K Clusters generated using K Means Clustering, how do we calculate the area of each cluster? Is there any formula for it?

I have already tried gArea() with the rgeos package but I get an error code of "

> unable to find an inherited method for function is.projected for signature kmeans

the cluster analysis works perfectly, I only need a way to find the area of each cluster. so either a formula using withiness, totss and betweeness or some help with the code would really be appreciates

the cluster analysis works perfectly, I only need a way to find the area of each cluster. so far for the graphing part I have :

```
###################### Clustering Script
clusters <- kmeans(df[2:3], k)

# Save the cluster number in the dataset as column 'Borough'
df$clusterId <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)
m_color=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", 
"#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7","#A09999","#B99F00","#E6E4E9", 
"#777E73", "#D1A142", "#33AAB2", "#99CC00")

fviz_cluster(clusters, data = df[2:3], 
             ellipse.type = "norm",
             ellipse.level = 0.99,
             palette = m_color,
             geom = "point",
             axes = c(0,0), 
             show.clust.cent = TRUE,
             ggtheme = theme_minimal()
             )

clusters$totss
clusters$size
clusters$centers
clusters$withinss
clusters$betweenss
gArea(clusters, byid = FALSE)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the area of a cluster? Clusters are finite clouds of points, and the total area a finite collection of points is zero. Perhaps you mean something like the area of the convex hull of the cluster? What dimension is this in? If it is dimension 2, area would make sense, but in higher dimensions the relevant idea would be volume or hypervolume.

Comment: yes, the convex hull of the cluster, it is  in dimension 2

Answer (score 3):

Using the example in `example(kmeans)` we can take the convex hull of the points and then use polyarea to compute the area.

```
library(geometry)

set.seed(123)
example(kmeans)  # creates input x and kmeans output cl

# area of convex hull of points in the cluster
area <- function(z) { xy <- z[chull(z), ]; polyarea(xy[,1], xy[,2]) }
sapply(split(as.data.frame(x), cl$cluster), area)
##         1         2         3         4         5 
## 0.3758644 0.4127252 0.2722848 0.2090896 0.3283888 

# area  of box bounding all points in the cluster
area.box <- function(z) diff(range(z[, 1])) * diff(range(z[, 2]))
sapply(split(as.data.frame(x), cl$cluster), area.box)
##         1         2         3         4         5 
## 0.6570733 0.7924508 0.4263473 0.3307718 0.5639517 

# area of largest ellipse in the bounding box
area.ellipse <- function(z) pi * diff(range(z[, 1])) * diff(range(z[, 2])) / 4
sapply(split(as.data.frame(x), cl$cluster), area.ellipse)
##         1         2         3         4         5 
## 0.5160641 0.6223894 0.3348524 0.2597876 0.4429267
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting some odd results, im not sure what exactly is the "area" with this result, because the numbers seem way to small for any of them to be considered areas,

Comment: Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:

[1] 8.393272 9.584092

 (between_SS / total_SS =  74.4 %)

Comment: betweenss    52.38021 52.38021

tot.withinss 17.97736 17.97736

totss        70.35757 70.35757



kmeans> stopifnot(all.equal(cl$ totss,        ss(x)),

kmeans+    all.equal(cl$ tot.withinss, ss(resid.x)),

kmeans+    ## these three are the same:

Comment: `area` is the area of the polygon forming the convex hull of the points in the cluster.  The sums of squares seem irrelevant to the question of area.

Comment: agreed, but i can not find a value for the area with this script, those are the only values that really come out, everything else seems to small to be the area

Comment: Have added fixes, `set.seed` to make it reproducible and 3 definitions of area.